# Call to a member function save() on int

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When using laravel eloquent update,

The query executed, but it instead of a successful response, it says `call to a member function save() on int in file .... line 43`

my update function looks like this:

```
public function removebookingbyid(Request $request) {
    $toUpdateColumns = ['is_delete' => 1, 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()];
    $data = InstructorSchedule::where('id', $request->booking_id)
        ->update($toUpdateColumns);

    $res = $data->save();

    if ($res) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>1,'msg'=>'ok'], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>0,'msg'=>'bad'], 500);
    }
}
```

I have a function almost the same to this one, the difference is that I only have 1 column to update, and it works well. But I don't know why this one gives me such error.

Comment: You don't need to `->save()` an `->update()` call. The `->update()` is sufficient on its own.

Comment: its because when you call `->update($toUpdateColumns);` it will run your update query and return integer value as a result of your query which is just an integer number so when you calling `$data->save();` its a meaningless statement and you can't call save on an `int`:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saving, saved, updating,
> and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models.
> This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

Maybe something like this will work :

```
$res = InstructorSchedule::findOrFail($request->booking_id);
$res->fill($toUpdateColumns);
$res->save();
```